# Sextic twist over BN elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am struggling to understand how to perform a sextic twist over a BN elliptic curve. This is what I understood so far:

Let's consider a BN elliptic curve:
$$
E: y^2=x^3+b
$$
And let's consider a point $Q \in E(F_{p^{12}}) $. What I would like to do is to "easily" go from/to $Q \in E(F_{p^{12}})$ to/from $Q' \in E'(F_{p^{2}})$, where $Q'$ is the sextic twist defined as
$$
E': y^2=x^3+b/\xi
$$
In fact I can use this isomorphism (I guess) to move from/towards $E$ and $E'$:
$$
\psi: E'(F_{p^2}) \rightarrow E(F_{p^{12}})
$$ $$
\psi((x',y')) = (\xi^{1/3}x',\xi^{1/2}y')
$$
$$
\psi^{-1}(x,y) = \left(\frac{x}{\xi^{1/3}},\frac{y}{\xi^{1/2}}\right)
$$
My questions are:

1. Is the isomorphism I wrote correct?
2. Is $\xi$ an integer number in $F_p$?
3. Can I choose **any** value I want for $\xi$? I guess that I should choose it so that $\xi^{1/3}$ and $\xi^{1/2}$ are integers, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2):

1. The map $\psi(x',y')$ is correct, but it is a homomorphism and not an isomorphism. The two curves have different numbers of points and so there can be no isomorphism between them. One can check that the map is a well-defined as for $x',y',\xi\in\mathbb F_{p^2}\Rightarrow \xi^{1/3}x',\xi^{1/2}y'\in\mathbb F_{p^{12}}$ and
   $$y'^2=x'^2+\frac b\xi\Rightarrow (\xi^{1/2}y')^2=(\xi^{1/3}x')^3+b.$$
   The homomorphism can be tediously checked by working through the addition formulae (note that the slope formula will scale by a factor of $\xi^{1/6}$). The inverse $\psi^{-1}$ function only lands on $E'(\mathbb F_{p^2})$ if $x/\xi^{1/3}$ and $y/\xi^{1/2}$ are both in $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ which will not be the case for a general point of $E(\mathbb F_{p^{12}})$. It will however be correct for any point on the subgroup of $E(\mathbb F_{p^{12}})$ that is the image of $\psi$.
2. and 3. For any value $\xi$ in $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ the map is defined. However, you should choose $\xi$ that is neither a square (in particular *not* an element of $\mathbb F_p$) nor a cube in $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ otherwise the image of $\psi$ will lie in $\mathbb F_{p^6}$ or $\mathbb F_{p^4}$ respectively and pairings between points in the image of $\psi$ will all be equal to 1.

Comment: Worth noting that the map can be clearly defined over the algebraic closure, where it is clearly an isomorphism.. (already over $F_{p^{12}}$).

Comment: @Fractalice Good point, I've added some ground field notation to make this explicit. Formally $$\psi: E(\overline{\mathbb F_p})\to E'(\overline{\mathbb F_p})$$ and $$\psi^{-1}:E'(\overline{\mathbb F_p})\to E(\overline{\mathbb F_p})$$ are both isomorphisms. For cryptographic purposes though we will always want to restrict to something finite.

Comment: I've modified the MathJax/LaTex in the above comment so that it renders. I hope the overline applies to what's intended. Where I stand the MathJax can be viewed with right click/Show Math As/TeX Commands.